# TYPO3 9.5.x allows capital letters in URL

Tags: .htaccess, typo3, slug, typo3-9.x

I updated TYPO3 to 9.5.19, but I can't use captial letters in the URL with the new routing. For example, I try to make it work for example.com/help and example.com/Help.
Is there any solution for this?
Regards

Comment: Issue is already discussed [here](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87544), you can use `EXT:justincase` by B13. You will find on TER as well as GitHub.

Comment: Amazing! That did the job. Thank you.

Comment: Great! I have given a detailed answer for better help to others ;) Inspired people to share!

Answer (score 0):

As you have already resolved the issue, let's summarize this and close this question!

So, Issue is already listed on the issue tracker, here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87544

To fix this, we have TYPO3 extension called `EXT:justincase` (Thanks to @Benni Mack and #B13 Team!) available on TER and GitHub both. Find URL below:

- [TER](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/justincase)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/b13/justincase)

This extension allows you to use case sensitive URL for your site if your server supported.

Yeah, that's it!